# I got two scripts that works perfectly, but when I combined them it does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to combined two simply scripts that works, but when combined it does not work. can anyone tell me why?

I don't understand what happened here can anyone explain to me or can anyone tell me how can i combined two scripts

```
function Script1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 7).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=edate(R[0]C[-3],1)');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=now()');
};



function Script2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};



function Combined() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 7).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=edate(R[0]C[-3],1)');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=now()');


  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts are getting the current cell then use `activate()` which changes the current cell so the "start point" for the second part is not the same as the one for the first part.

Comment: thanks ruben. i just want to be sure how would you write this script? and by the way you would notice that i have repeat "spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).activate();" this is to select the 1st column of the row. any script for this? thank you so.much

Comment: @zyburg On my scripts I have not used `getNextDataCell` and I use `offset` and `activate` very rarely. Instead I use very frequently the different variants of `getRange` and `getDataRange`